# How to move files that are not in use?

Tags: linux, bash, lsof

I want to move files in a directory that are not currently in use.  I have a sense that some combination of `lsof`, `find`, and `xargs` could work but I can't quite get there.  So far, I created the following command:

`lsof mydir/*|awk '(NR>1){print $9}`

This gives me a list of files that ARE being used.  If I could just get a list of files that are NOT being used, then something like xargs could issue a `mv` on those files.  I just can't seem to find an elegant way of doing this.  Does anyone have any hints for me?

Comment: This seems like a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/ask?title=How%20to%20move%20files%20that%20are%20not%20in%20use%3F&tags=linux+bash+lsof) or [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=How%20to%20move%20files%20that%20are%20not%20in%20use%3F&tags=linux+bash+lsof)

Comment: You might have to break out the big guns, and script in python and perl to parse the `lsof` output into a map, and then do the walk operation, excluding opened files, to build up the list of files to move. However I wonder why you can't just move all files in the first place?

Comment: Another idea might be to move everything, then move anything open back to the original location? Assuming the move preserves enough information of course.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek:  Why?  This is a programming question.  I'm not asking how to use `ls`, I'm trying write a bash script.

Comment: @User1 You are? You didn't mention bash scripts anywhere in your question, it sounds like you're just looking for a command you can run in a shell

Comment: @Douglas Leeder:  Some of the files are open because another process is actually writing to them.  Thus, I wouldn't want to move an incomplete file..it would be corrupted.

Comment: @User1 That shouldn't be true; you can move a file around and open file handles will still work. You can even erase a file and programs that have it open can keep reading from it

Comment: As long as the file does not cross filesystem boundaries there should be no problem with moving it. If the file is not constantly open but is instead being opened, appended-to, and then closed, repeatedly, then there could be a problem.

Comment: So let me understand..let's say I'm writing a huge gzip file.  As it's being created, I realize that I don't have enough space.  I `mv` it to another disk.  The `gzip` process will not contiue writing without interruption and the new file will continue to grow after it is moved?  Also, will space on the original disk be freed once all the data is moved off of that disk?

Comment: @User1: No, because that's a different filesystem.

Comment: @Dennis:  Bummer.  I was hoping it would work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Sorpigal's suggestion, I found an easy way to make this work without loops:

`comm -2 -3 <(find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f|sort) <(sudo lsof $dir/* | awk '(NR>1) {print $9}'|sort) | xargs -I {} mv {} $move_dir`

I'm not sure of race conditions but it doesn't matter in my case.  The files are opened once for writing and then should be closed until moved.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it this way.

```
find $dir -maxdepth 1 | sort > $other_dir/all_files
lsof $dir/* | awk '(NR>1) {print $9}' | sort > $other_dir/in_use_files
comm -2 -3 $other_dir/all_files $other_dir/in_use_files
```

From comm(1):

```
NAME
       comm - compare two sorted files line by line

SYNOPSIS
       comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2

    ...

       -2     suppress lines unique to FILE2

       -3     suppress lines that appear in both files
```

Now it's a simple matter of reformatting into a series of `mv` statements. Perhaps like this:

```
while IFS= read file ; do
    mv "$file" "$destination/"
done < <(comm -2 -3 all_files in_use_files)
```

Or using another intermediate file if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using `comm` that puts everything together.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the best way, but one can just code it up in a few minutes:

get your list of open files (sort if not already)

get a list of all files (sort if not already)

diff the two lists

xargs whatever

The number of steps here will make obvious something that should have been a concern anyway, which is race conditions - the files that are in use when you select them may not be the files that are in use when you actually move them.

Comment: Great point about race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

It's what fuser is meant for.

```
/var/log/apache2
$ fuser access.log
/var/log/apache2/access.log: 2132 15456 16414 19555 19622
/var/log/apache2
$ fuser access.log 2>/dev/null
 2132 15456 16414 19555 19622
/var/log/apache2
$ if [ ! -z "$(fuser access.log 2>/dev/null)" ]
> then
>   echo "this file is in use"
> else
>   echo "this file is not in use"
> fi
this file is in use
```